# How to get a access token in OAuth + Websphere? (After checking)

Tags: java, security, oauth, websphere, access-token

I am using OAuth in Websphere. I get an access token and validate the access in my path. The validation is working but, later that, I call to a WebBean and I need to get de access token. I tried to take the parameter from Request but returns null.

Some suggestion?

Regards
Emiliano

Answer (score 0):

1. This is the preferred and recommended way to get the access_token out of current process.

   ```
   String accessToken = null;
   Subject subj = WSSubject.getRunAsSubject();
   Set<WSOAuth20Token> credentials = subj.getPrivateCredentials(WSOAuth20Token.class);
   if (credentials != null)
   {
       WSOAuth20Token oauth2token =  credentials.iterator().next();
       accessToken = oauth2token.getTokenString();
   }
   ```
2. If you really want to read it again from request parameter, you could follow this instruction which may work, but I do not want to recommend it and did not test it. https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/rweb_custom_props.html#enablemultiplereadsofpostdata

Comment: Thanks for your comments! I will try it. Regards ERA

Comment: Which is the package of WSOAuth20Token.class?

Comment: com.ibm.wsspi.security.oauth20.token.WSOAuth20Token

Comment: Thanks. It works but only in the first intent. In the second intent, doesn't works... Any idea?

Comment: First intent: [4/07/17 10:55:26:878 ART] 00000029 SystemOut     O [Provider:OAuthProvider,user:wasadmin,client:user,expiration:Tue Jul 04 11:54:14 ART 2017,token:ViZVrhloVHEL0W9agltttXMSPEyRxh8waXzL6fZ8,, {OAuthProvider=OAuthProvider, com.ibm.wsspi.security.cred.cacheKey=OAuthProvider-1640529005}, com.ibm.ws.security.token.SingleSignonTokenImpl@d24fd57d, com.ibm.ws.security.token.AuthenticationTokenImpl@d99715e0, com.ibm.ws.security.token.AuthorizationTokenImpl@c32580e1]

Comment: Second intent: [4/07/17 10:55:59:100 ART] 00000033 SystemOut     O [{com.ibm.wsspi.security.cred.cacheKey=OAuthProvider-1640529005, OAuthProvider=OAuthProvider}, com.ibm.ws.security.token.SingleSignonTokenImpl@41ba4c56, com.ibm.ws.security.token.AuthenticationTokenImpl@dd223da2, com.ibm.ws.security.token.AuthorizationTokenImpl@3d4c239e]

Comment: can you tell me the difference between working and failing scenarios? For the failing case, seems the code is executed in a different java process (or different replication domain).

Comment: Without differences I think... I expand the explanation. I have a link to call to WebBean with access token. Example: https://IP:PORT/wps/myportal/PATH-WITH-VALIDATION/?access_token=KHThLTEvsV9jpz2clgcHIHmdeMjX3VaAe7wZl2D2. When I click in this link for the first intent, it works... I access to WebBean and I get the access token. Later, I click in the same link and I access to the WebBean but I cant to get the access token.

Comment: any idea about this situation?

Comment: I have was debuging... I lose a private credencial in the second intent... I don't know why... This is my lost credential: 

Provider:OAuthProvider,user:wasadmin,client:user,expiration:Mon Jul 10 12:58:48 ART 2017,token:8sDHOLwfK7CB915Z6fvom6FdZxVpz38OU0wbvTgm                      Any help?

Comment: Can The token have some special configuration about this situation?

Comment: Hi Emiliano, will you be able to collect a trace? and send it to IBM support by opening an PMR? The trace String is com.ibm.ws.security.*=all=enabled

Comment: Ok. I will send the report! Thanks!